# Lombok and jackson - Conflicting/ambiguous property name definitions

Tags: java, jackson, lombok

I get a WARN message:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Conflicting/ambiguous property name definitions (implicit name 'balance'): found multiple explicit names: [{}Balance, Balance], but also implicit accessor: [method ResponseVO#getBalance(0 params)][visible=true,ignore=false,explicitName=false]
```

I have latest lombok 1.18.10 and fasterxml.jackson-version 2.7.5

I found [similar issue](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1122) but it should have been fixed in 2.7.4 (closed)

> Jackson 2.7.1 and Lombok: 'Conflicting/ambiguous property name definitions' #1122
>
> I think this can be changed for 2.7.4 after all, can fix this.

Code:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ResponseVO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Balance")
    @JsonProperty("Balance")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    List<BalanceResponseVO> balance;
```

Is it relevant warning ? how can I fix/remove this warning?

It seems that new Lombok version added  `@JsonProperty("Balance")` to generated setter also and create this confusion

**EDIT**

Issue fixed when I removed `@JsonProperty("Balance")` which is actually unneeded in my case

Comment: Does the warning go away when you make the field `private`?

Comment: @JanRieke It was fixed when I removed `@JsonProperty("Balance")`

Comment: @user7294900 IMHO you should do a proper answer out of your edit.

Comment: @JanRieke `private` didn't fix it

Comment: @UserWhoMarkAsUnreproducable, it's reproducible and real issue when adding `@JsonProperty` with new lombok 1.18.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We upgrade Lombok version and it now added `@JsonProperty("Balance")` also to generated setter

This duplicate `@JsonProperty` created a WARN in log and also failed creating response (without exception)

I removed `@JsonProperty("Balance")` which is actually redundant/unneeded in my case and it works

- Note changing to `private` didn't fixed the issue

[Lombok change](https://projectlombok.org/changelog):

> FEATURE: Lombok now knows exactly how to treat @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty and will copy it to the right places for example when making builders. Issue #1961 Issue #1981